# Change column datatype from VARCHAR to BIGINT in phoenix table

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I have an existing apache phoenix table that has all the columns defined as VARCHAR. I want to change the datatype of one of the columns to BIGINT. Is this possible in phoenix? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
alter table(:table_to_alter) do
  modify :column_to_alter, :bigint
end
```

Then you also want to change the schema as follows since all integer types will be mapped to `:integer` in elixir...

```
schema "table_to_alter" do
  field :column_to_alter, :integer
end
```

Comment: Getting this error running the above command from sqlline.py client: 
Error: ERROR 601 (42P00): Syntax error. Encountered "do" at line 1, column 57. (state=42P00,code=601)
org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixParserException: ERROR 601 (42P00): Syntax error. Encountered "do" at line 1, column 57.
        at org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixParserException.newException(PhoenixParserException.java:33)

Comment: My question is regarding apache-phoenix database, not the phoenix web framewrok.